# hover selector moving svg inside search bar

Tags: html, css

When I hover over my search bar, the SVG I have included inside the search bar moves down and to the right, I was wondering how to stop this and keep it static in its original place?

The text and SVG works as expected for the focus selector and I was able to keep the text static for the hover selector, however I am unable to keep the SVG static and in its place when hovering.

```
<div class="search-container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
  </form>
</div>
```

```
.search-container input[type=text] {
  font-family: 'SF Compact Display';
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.22;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #999999;
  padding-left: 56px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('searchIcon.svg');
  background-position: 16px 10px; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.search-container input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 0.5px #ececec;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.search-container input:focus {
  outline: solid 1.5px #ececec;
}

.search-container input[type=text]:focus {
  outline: solid 1.5px #ececec;
}

.search-container input:hover {
  border: solid 1.5px #ececec;
  padding-left: 55px;
}

.search-container input[type=text]:hover {
  border: solid 1.5px #ececec;
  padding-left: 55px;
}
```

Comment: Well if you are messing with the border width and padding of the element on hover, you’ll have to account for that in your background image positioning …

Comment: I added the padding-left: 55px to stop the search text from moving to the right when I hovered over it

Comment: Including the actual icon will help us understand the issue better. You can use a third party hosting service like imgur